# How to name thread for logging with concurrent.futures?

Tags: python-3.x, logging, concurrent.futures

I am creating a webscraper that would scrape from multiple domains in different threads. As there are many different domains, I would like to be able to search logged info per each thread.

**UPDATE: solution implemented in code. Follow # SOLUTION lines**

The script has been set up as follows:

```
import logging
from queue import Queue, Empty
from threading import current_thread # SOLUTION
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

logging.basicConfig(
    format='%(threadName)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s',
    level=logging.INFO
)


class Scraper:
    def __init__(self, max_workers):
        self.pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers = max_workers,  thread_name_prefix='T')
        self.to_crawl = Queue()
        for task in self.setup_tasks(tasks=max_workers):
            logging.info('Putting task to queue:\n{}'.format(task))
            self.to_crawl.put(task)
        logging.info('Queue size after init: {}'.format(self.to_crawl.qsize()))

    def setup_tasks(self, cur, tasks=1):
        # Prepare tasks for the queue

    def run_task(self, task):
        # Function for executing the task
        current_thread().name = task['id'] # SOLUTION
        logging.info('Executing task:\n{}'.format(task))
        id = task['id'] # I want the task id to be reflected in the logging function for when run_task runds

    def run_scraper(self):
        while True:
            logging.info('Launching new thread, queue size is {}'.format(self.to_crawl.qsize()))
            try:
                task = self.to_crawl.get()
                self.pool.submit(self.run_task, task)
            except Empty:
                break    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = Scraper(max_workers=3)
    s.run_scraper()
```

I would like to add the `task['id']` to the logging formatting configuration instead of the given `%(threadName)s` without doing it manually each time the script logs something in `run_task`

**Is there a way to assign `task['id']` to the thread `%(threadName)s` when the thread takes the task in `run_scraper`?**

Comment: I guess, you may just add `threading.current_thread().name = "my_name_la_la"` at the very start of the worker function. Of course, you should pass to the worker function all the data you wanna include into the name of the thread. Probably, another option is to use Python 3.7 and `ThreadPoolExecutor` with `initializer` argument.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Poolka! I added `threading.current_thread().name = task['id']` to the first row of `run_task` and now I get it nicely in the logs with `%(threadName)s`. Simple and elegant!

Just out of curiosity, how would you implement it with `ThreadPoolExecutor` with `initializer` argument?

Comment: I am on Python 3.6 now. I've never tried `ThreadPoolExecutor` with `initializer` so I'm not aware of implementation details.